# Angular2 how to refference directive in typescript

Tags: angular

I want to refference modal in my code so i can call show hide when i need it

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {CORE_DIRECTIVES} from '@angular/common';

// todo: change to ng2-bootstrap
import {MODAL_DIRECTVES, BS_VIEW_PROVIDERS, ModalDirective} from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';
// webpack html imports
let template = require('./section.modal.html');

@Component({
  selector: 'section-modal',
  directives: [MODAL_DIRECTVES, CORE_DIRECTIVES],
  viewProviders:[BS_VIEW_PROVIDERS],
  template: template
})
export class SectionModalComponent {
    public lgModal: any;
    show(id){
        console.log(this.lgModal);
        alert("show"+id);
    }
}
```

Template

```
<div bsModal #lgModal="bs-modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" (click)="lgModal.hide()" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Large modal</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I thought that i could use **#lgModal** but the problem is that this variable is visible only from template.

How can i access this from typescript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
export class SectionModalComponent {
    @ViewChild('lgModal') lgModal: ElementRef;
    show(id){
        console.log(this.lgModal); //ElementRef
        console.log(this.lgModal.nativeElement); // HTMLElement
        alert("show"+id);
    }
}
```